# foreach statement cannot ooperate on variables of type UnityEngine.GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So as title says, this is my problem. I tried 2 different ways of solving it:

First is with this code:

```
var children = GetComponentInChildren<GameObject>();
foreach(var child in children)
{
    if(child.name == "HealthBar")
    {
        HealthBar = child;
    }
}
```

Which gives me `Unknown Resolve Error` on `var` inside `foreach` loop.

Second is this:

```
var children = GetComponentInChildren<GameObject>();
foreach(GameObject child in children)
{
    if(child.name == "HealthBar")
    {
        HealthBar = child;
    }
}
```

Which gives me error in the title.

What should i do? Everywhere i looked how to get object inside object by name, everywhere is done by first example.

Comment: `GetComponentInChildren<GameObject>()` returns a single `GameObject` instance? You can't/don't need to loop if only one object is returned. I don't know what `GetComponentInChildren` does but maybe you meant `GetComponentInChildren<IEnumerable<GameObject>>()`?

Comment: Yea. I haven't noticed there is `GetComponentsInChildren`. Problem was that `S`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the `Transform` component, not the `GameObject` type (which is not a component by the way). Moreover, as @Keith Nesbitt indicated, mind the `s` at `GetComponentsInChildren`

```
var children = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
foreach(var child in children)
{
    if(child.name == "HealthBar")
    {
        HealthBar = child;
    }
}
```

An extension method you could try :

```
public static void Traverse( this GameObject gameobject, System.Action<GameObject> callback )
{
    Transform transform = gameobject.transform;
    for ( int childIndex = 0 ; childIndex < transform.childCount ; ++childIndex )
    {
        GameObject child = transform.GetChild( childIndex ).gameObject;
        child.Traverse( callback );
        callback( child );
    }
}

// ...

gameObject.Traverse( ( go ) =>
{
    if(go.name == "HealthBar")
    {
        HealthBar = go ;
    }
} ) ;
```

Comment: `S` was my problem but thanks for this `Traverse` method.

Answer (score 2):

[`GetComponentInChildren<T>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) only returns a single result, whereas what you want is [`GetComponentsInChildren<T>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html), which returns all of the given type.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` only works on things that implement `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerable`.

`GetComponentInChildren<T>()` returns a single `T`, in your example you pass in `GameObject` as the `T`, however `GameObject` is not something you can iterate over (i.e it does not implement `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerable` according to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html)).

Perhaps you meant to pass something different into `GetComponentInChildren<T>()`?  I am not too familiar with Unity or what you are trying to accomplish, but `GameObject` does have a method called [`GetComponentsInChildren<T>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html) (note the plural in the name), maybe that's what you are looking for?